# Backup or snaphot tool for ext4

Tags: backup, dump, snapshot, ext4

I'm looking for a backup tool for ext4, which can take a copy from a running fs like /var with no collisions after recover such fs. I know BSD dump has an '-L' option, which tells him to work on a snapshot. But nor dump nor dumpe2fs from repository have such option. I've read about a [patchset](https://github.com/amir73il/ext4-snapshots/commits/for-ext4-v1) for ext4 providing snapshot support, but replies about it are very different, so i'm here to ask about your experience with this patches.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a dump tool but I use `rsync` which allows incremental backups between 2 filesystems on a running system.

for example
    rsync -aSXvH /srcdir /target_dir

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it a bit later. Does it support deltas?

Comment: Yes - it will only sync what has changed since the last sync.

Comment: But it doesn't suit in that case. If a directory always updates, a snapshot will have collisions while rsync.

Comment: Explain what you want more clearly and you may get more help.